# Jquery / Ajax - Working with a class that is appendet after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 ajax calls that takes data from input fields and send those to the server and create a new database record. If the save was successfull, I append a new html table row to my html table.

The seccond ajax call send an ID that belongs to a specific cost point to my server and deletes this record from the database.

Both of the calls works finde. However, if I create a html record and want to delete it again ( without refreshing the page ) it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
function addNewRow(id, name, cost) {
        $('#costTable tr:last').after('<tr data-id="'+id+'"><td><i class="material-icons">delete forever</i></td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + cost + '</td></tr>>');
    }

$(document).on('click', '#saveCost', function () {
            var name = $("input[name='cost-name']").val();
            var cost = $("input[name='cost-price']").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{ route('saveCost') }}",
                data: {'name': name, 'cost': cost},
                success: function (data) {
                    swal({
                        position: 'top-right',
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Kostenpunkt wurde gespeichert',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1000
                    });
                    $("input[name='cost-name']").val("");
                    $("input[name='cost-price']").val("");
                    addNewRow(data, name, cost);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            }); //end of ajax
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.deleteCost', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var costID = $this.closest('tr').data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{ route('deleteCost') }}",
                data: {'costID': costID},
                success: function (data) {
                    swal({
                        position: 'top-right',
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Kostenpunkt wurde gelöscht',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1000
                    });
                    $this.closest('tr').remove();
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            }); //end of ajax
        });
```

Thats the table:

```
    <table class="table" id="costTable">
         <thead class="text-primary">
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Kostenpunkt</th>
              <th>Kosten</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
               @foreach($costs as $cost)
                     <tr data-id="{{ $cost->id }}">
                          <td><i class="material-icons deleteCost">delete forever</i></td>
                          <td>{{ $cost->name }}</td>
                          <td class="text-primary">{{ $cost->cost }}</td>
                     </tr>
               @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

After I created a new row and want to delete it again ( without refreshing the page ), it won't work. I think it's because I append the data in the "saveCost" ajax Call and the appended data doesn't belong to the actual HTML DOM.

Comment: Do you have pass back Id in first call ? Can you console.log (data) - do you see Id of new record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot, in the `addNewRow` function, to add the class name `deleteCost` to this element: `<i class="material-icons">delete forever</i>`. Add this class and delete will work as you expect.

Comment: Oh you're right !! oh man I was so stupid.. haven't seen it :D Thanks for your help! works perfect now. I will mark your answer as correct :)